# Bigquery: Join date-partitioned table such that output table remains date-partitioned

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got an event store in a date-partitioned table in bigquery called `pageviews`.  I've got a big table called `metadata` I'd like to join it with to enrich my pageviews.  I want to scan all data only once to keep costs down and I want the output to go into a date-partitioned table.  How can I accomplish this?

I already know that I can make a separate join query for each date-partition in `pageview` and save the output into another date-partitioned table.  However that requires scanning my `metadata` once for each partition.  I want to avoid that.